# How to use Ajax Loader in jQuery pop up

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Please tell me how to use Ajax Loader in jQuery pop up.

On my aspx page there is jquery pop up, and on the pop up there is list of checkboxes, and when a check box is checked another list of checkboxes load. For this I want use Ajax Loader.

Answer (score 1):

Add a div with the loading gif and hide it. Then use the following snippet:

```
$("#loading").ajaxStart(function(){
   $(this).show();
 });
$("#loading").ajaxStop(function(){
   $(this).hide();
 });
```

This will show your loading gif each time an ajax request is loading.